# What are Some OpenID Alternatives

Tags: c#, openid

I am trying to integrate OpenID into my website but I am discovering OpenID website is still buggy. Does anyone know a good alternative.

Comment: I guess you could start by trying out the various OpenID servies Stack Overflow uses :)

Comment: OpenID isn't a website, it is a standard that can be hosted by anyone.  What website are you having problems with?  Is it one of the providers or the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CAS, shibboleth, LDAP...

Answer (score 4):

what about Windows Live ID?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404787.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[OAuth](http://oauth.net) is one used by Twitter and many others

Comment: OAuth is not the same as OpenID

Comment: OAuth isn't really a replacement for OpenID.  OpenID is Identity management, letting you have a single login credential for multiple websites.  OAuth is a method for you to authorize other services, like a twitter desktop client, to access your twitter data.

Comment: their site has some issues. I understand the difference between OpenId and OAuth but I think he may benefit from looking at OAuth implementation

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming you're asking for alternatives to a specific provider? check out the logins section of SO itself to see the various players out there.

Answer (score 0):

Depends upon what you are trying to achieve, but if you mean providing easy login access for your site you could try facebook connect.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
      <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the SlashID review at the web page below. It aims to be a OpenID competitor.

http://webtrends.about.com/od/openid/a/slashid_compare.htm

Answer (score 0):

MyOpenID.com may have been the site in question from the original poster (OP).  MyOpenID.com was a provider for Open IDs which closed 2014-02.
.:.
The Open ID Foundation website is at OpenID.net and they maintain a list of providers for Open IDs on their www.OpenID\Get-An-OpenID page.
.:.
SlashID as an alternative to Open ID did not seem to catch on. Currently there is a password manager with the name.
.:.
To learn more about Open Id, please visit their website: [Open ID Foundation](http://openid.net).
.:.
To setup an OpenID for yourself, find a provider at [OpenID Providers](http://openid.net/get-an-openid)